# no DOM in wordpress admin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dom

I correctly inserted a javascript file into the wordPress admin with :

```
 wp_enqueue_script()
```

I know that the script is loading. I tested it with an `alert()`.
I then found that I am unable to access the DOM. When I tried :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('load', function() {});
```

This error was:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

This is the first time I have used 'settings api' or inserted scripts into the WordPress admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want to add the load event handler to the `window` not the `body`. For one thing, the body doesn't exist until the BODY tag has been parsed. If your script is in the HEAD, then this is too soon to attach anything to the body. So, if you want a script to not run until the DOM is loaded, you can't achieve that by trying to add an event handler to an object in the DOM.

I would *strongly* recommend using a JS framework to handle this. Adding your own function to run on page load is something you want to be cross-browser compatible and readily extensible. The major JS frameworks have solve this problem already and there's little to be gained in trying to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You code is probably executing before the DOM is fully loaded and `<body>` is not available. If you want to run a function on load, I would use `jQuery.ready()` as jQuery is already available in Wordpress by default:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ /* your code */ });
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false);
```

or

```
window.onload=load; // onload will work in all browsers so use this
```

and your handler

```
function load(){ ... }
```

You can also follow the `Fabrício Matté`'s approach.

Comment: Yes this is a nice approach, `window.onload` works in all browsers -- but you have to take care to don't overwrite it if you have more than 1 script using it. The `DOMContentLoaded` is very nice, but doesn't work in older versions of IE.

Comment: Now that I come to think about it, older versions of IE wouldn't even support the `addEventListener` method so yeah, +1 because your answer is the only that utilizes pure JS to solve the issue - even though `window.onload` will execute only once all the images have been loaded, it will work even on IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Enqueue the script at the `footer` of the page.

You won't need a DOM ready handler much less a load listener then.
And also as @Dancrumb answered, `load` is a `window` event and not `body`'s.

By default, WP enqueues scripts at the `head`. You can't access the `body` element directly from the `head` without a listener/deferred execution because the DOM parser simply didn't reach the `body` tag yet. By putting the scripts in the footer, it ensures that the DOM is already ready for your script to run.

The syntax for [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
     $handle
    ,$src
    ,$deps
    ,$ver
    ,$in_footer 
);
```

So for your use case, set the 5th option to `true`.